# How do I print these characters?

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
"\\xB9 blah\n   blah: \xbf\xaa\xb7\xa2\xb2\xbf\n"
```

I want this to be printed as:

```
\\xB9 blah
   blah: \\xbf\\xaa\\xb7\\xa2\\xb2\\xbf
```

I have tried:

```
s = "\\xB9 blah\n   blah: \xbf\xaa\xb7\xa2\xb2\xbf\n"
s = s.replace(r'\x',r'\\x')                                                     
print s
```

but this prints out funny looking characters on the second line after blah:. How do I get this to work?

Comment: Are these the characters that print: `¿ª·¢²¿`? Those look like extended-ASCII hex values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\xNN` notation in a string translates to the character with code `NN`. In order for your `replace` method to do what you intend, you need to provide it with a string where it can find the substring `\x`. You can use raw string, or simply escape the backslashes :

```
s = r"\\xB9 blah\n   blah: \xbf\xaa\xb7\xa2\xb2\xbf\n"
s = s.replace(r'\x',r'\\x')
```

.

```
s = "\\xB9 blah\n   blah: \\xbf\\xaa\\xb7\\xa2\\xb2\\xbf\n"
s = s.replace(r'\x',r'\\x')
```

If you want to print the escaped versions of the litteral characters, that's a bit more tricky. Assuming you only want the extended ASCII chars to be escaped, I'd do:

```
def escape_non_ascii(s):
    out = ''
    for c in s:
        if 31 < ord(c) < 127:
            out += c
        elif c == '\n':
            out += r'\n'
        else:
            out += r'\x{0:x}'.format(ord(c))
    return out

print escape_non_ascii("\\xB9 blah\n   blah: \xbf\xaa\xb7\xa2\xb2\xbf\n")
```

Comment: This pretty much did the trick except I didn't make the newline raw as this would display \n rather than given me an actual newline.

Comment: @smithy If you want actual line-feeds, you can replace `out += r'\n'` with `out += '\n'` *(Remove the 'r')*...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
s = r"\\xB9 blah\n   blah: \xbf\xaa\xb7\xa2\xb2\xbf\n"
for part in s.split('\\n'):
    print part
```